# Deprecation Warning for ActiveSupport Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to open a rails console and keep giving me that error :

```
 roberto@Fofa-Dell:/mnt/c/Users/farid/skyscrapper$ rails c
 /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121:
 warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
 /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121:
 warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
 /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
 `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep
 (SystemStackError)
         from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
 `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
         from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
 `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
         from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
 `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
         from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
 `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
         from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
 `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
         from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
 `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
         from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
 `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
         from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in
 `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
          ... 4036 levels...
         from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in
 `run_command!'
         from /home/roberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in
 `<top (required)>'
         from bin/rails:4:in `require'
         from bin/rails:4:in `<main>' roberto@Fofa-Dell:/mnt/c/Users/farid/skyscrapper$
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing? I installed all the required gems, stopped sprint, and I'm still getting this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your error is because of your ruby/rails versions.

See [Rails issue on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27670)

To update your rails/ruby versions:

Ruby -- go to the [ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) downloads page and follow the instructions for your operating system.

Rails -- go to the github instructions for [updating rails](http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html)

Comment: how can i get arround that

Comment: thank you , I did update the rails to version 5.0.0 and it worked.  now can u help how to add chromedriver path on bash

Comment: i upgrade rails to 5.0.0 and it worked. thank you Rosalynn

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not familiar with Chromedriver. You could open a new question for that if you can't find anything addressing it already.